# How do I change this query?

Tags: php, sql

How do i change the SELECT query from this:

```
$tre = mysql_query("SELECT System_id, Full_name FROM accounts 
WHERE Full_name LIKE '". mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q'])."%' LIMIT 5");
```

To having this query below in $tre:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contacts.friend_id, accounts.full_name, 
accounts.system_id
FROM contacts, accounts
WHERE (contacts.system_id = '$sid' AND contacts.friend_id 
= accounts.system_id) OR (contacts.friend_id = '$sid' 
AND contacts.system_id = accounts.system_id)
```

I want the to place the second query inside of $tre = mysql_query();

I am having trouble doing so because the second query has brackets in them and being new i am not sure how to do it correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  Are you asking us how to copy and paste?  Can you reword your question?  What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, i clarified.  please check again.

Comment: Where does the $sid come from?  Also, the brackets do not affect the query. just place it inside the double quotations and PHP will know to send the whole query to MySQL.

Comment: @tlunter.  Please write your solution as an answer.  It worked! So i can accept it as a answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, the brackets do not affect the query. just place it inside the double quotations and PHP will know to send the whole query to MySQL.

Also: If $sid comes from any user input put something like this in place of $sid:

`" . mysql_real_escape_string($sid) . "`